# Redux: Create root reducer from combineReducers and "loose" properties

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I want to create a Redux store that has this shape:

```
store = {
  loaded: Boolean,
  loading: Boolean,
  view: Object, // uses combineReducers
  layers: Object // uses combineReducers
}
```

So far, my root reducer looks like this:

**rootReducer.js**

```
import view from './view';
import layers from './layers';

const initialState = {
  loaded: false,
  loading: false,
};

function loadState(state = initialState, action = {}) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'LOADED':
      return {
        ...state,
        loaded: true,
        loading: false,
      };

    case 'LOADING':
      return {
        ...state,
        loaded: false,
        loading: true,
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default combineReducers({
  view,
  layers,
  // hmmmm, putting loadState here would give me a loadState object property,
  // not loose 'loaded' and 'loading' properties
});
```

How do I also have these "loose" properties like `loaded` and `loading` alongside them?

Comment: reducers are pure functions. The way you think reducers are objects. You must turn `loaded` and `loading` into functions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

@PhiNguyen is right, I need to turn these loaded/loading properties into their own reducers!

```
import { LOADED, LOADING } from '../ActionTypes';

export function loaded(state = false, action = {}) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case LOADED:
      return true;

    case LOADING:
      return false;

    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export function loading(state = false, action = {}) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case LOADED:
      return false;

    case LOADING:
      return true;

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

**rootReducer.js**

```
import { loaded, loading } from './load';
import view from './view';
import layers from './layers';

export default combineReducers({
  loaded,
  loading,
  view,
  layers
});
```

Answer (score 13):

Sometimes I find writing individual reducers for a few simple properties to be obnoxious overhead, so I have a `combineReducersWithRoot` utility I use sometimes.

```
export function combineReducersWithRoot(rootReducer, reducers) {
  return (state, action) => {
    // Ensure the root state object is a new object; otherwise
    // React may not re-render.
    let newState = {...rootReducer(state, action)};
    Object.keys(reducers).forEach(domain => {
      let obj = state ? state[domain] : undefined;
      newState[domain] = reducers[domain](obj, action);
    });
    return newState;
  };
}
```

Now, given a state structure something like this:

```
{
  loading: bool
  loaded: bool
  data: {
    filter: string
    arr: object[]
  }
}
```

You can do this:

```
function rootReducer(state = {loading: false, loaded: false}, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case STARTED_LOADING:
      return {...state, loading: true, loaded: false};
    case FINISHED_LOADING:
      return {...state, loading: false, loaded: true};
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

function dataReducer(state = {filter: '', arr: []}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_FILTER:
      return {...state, filter: action.value};
    case SET_DATA:
      return {...state, arr: action.arr};
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default combineReducersWithRoot(rootReducer, {data: dataReducer});
```

Comment: Just so others avoid confusion, you should modify this so that `return newState` is actually `return {...newState}`, otherwise changes to the sub state won't cause connect() to re-render since it is technically the same state object.

Comment: Good note, thanks. I tweaked the code to address this, though slightly differently from your suggestion.

Comment: I ran into issues with this function as I had actions on the root reducer that modified state in branches, which was being clobbered by the branch reducer's default state. I solved this by only assigning the branch reducer's new state if it wasn't exactly the same object as before

Comment: I too, like @rsheldiii, had rootReducer modifying branch states. I solved it modifying the first line inside the loop: `let obj = newState ? newState[domain] : undefined;`